# Swap screens in plasma

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

I have two screens set to two monitors in plasma (Kubuntu 18.04). Is there a way to "swap" the two screens between the two monitors? (The two screens are the same resolution.) I can switch the "primary" screen with xrandr:

```
xrandr --output <display_name> --primary
```

but that only swaps the desktop (background, icons, panels), an not the windows. On the other hand, there are kwin shortcuts for Window to Next/Previous Screen, but I'd like to apply that to all windows at once, and not one by one. There's a Switch to Next/Previous Screen shortcut to, but I don't know what it does (tried it, don't see any difference).

The scenario is that I have a second computer plugged to one of the monitors, which I use sporadically. In case the shared monitor is showing the second computer, I have no way of seeing what the first computer should be showing there. I'd like a way to switch screens so I can see it in the other monitor, that should be faster than going through the shared monitor's menus to select input source.

Answer (score 1):

Really - no. The image on the display is linked to the unique EDID information of this display. Even if you swap the display ports, the pictures will remain on their displays.

This property is deep in the [WDDM/VidPN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/introduction-to-video-present-networks) structure and there are no ready-made tools for this.